# nuxt.js Configuring Localhost https server (but not in production)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have the following server configuration setup for my nuxt.js project:

```js
import path from 'path'
import fs from 'fs'

export default {
  ...
  
  server: {
    https: {
      key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.key')),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.crt'))
    }
  }
  
  ...
}
```

This all works great in local development - but we deploy to Netlify. And it causes issues when deployed in production.

So, I was wondering, what is the "trick" to turning certain configurations on and off in production inside `nuxt.config.js`...?

Answer (score 1):

You could use some conditionnal like

```js
baseURL: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https://nuxtjs.org' : 'https://dev.nuxtjs.org'
```

or env variables, having differents values in `.env` and in your Netlify dashboard.

Here is an interesting article on runtime env variables: https://nuxtjs.org/blog/moving-from-nuxtjs-dotenv-to-runtime-config/

And here is the official documentation about env variables: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-env/

Comment: So, something like: ```server: {
    https: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? {} : {
      key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.key')),
      cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'server.crt'))
    }
  }```?

Comment: I guess this one may work. I'm surprised this kind of thing is not stripped by itself tbh.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work ... I find process.env.NODE_ENV doesn't work well with SSR.

Comment: What do you mean ? The 2 are pretty much unrelated.

Comment: @MichealJ.Roberts Your solution works for me though